# Comparing angles of high dimensional vectors

Tags: vectors

I'm using cosine similarity to compare angles of 10000 dimensional vectors. This works fine, but I'm wondering if it's possible to instead, store the angles between certain vectors and a unit vector of the same dimension, then use those angles to compare them with each other.

Example:

I have a list of vectors $s = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and another list $t = (v_4, v_5, v_6)$

I then want to compare each vector in $s$ to each vector in $t$ and find the best matches (closest angle). That amounts to a total of $9$ comparisons.

My idea was that if I compute the angle between all of the vectors with a unit vectors (to have a baseline so to speak), then I can use those angles to match them with each other by checking which angles of vector to unit vector are closest with each other.
That way, I can reduce the number of computations by pre-calculating angles with unit vectors.

Problem is, this isn't working. The matches are completely wrong. With my limited understanding of math, I though that since I can visualize that working well on a 2D plane, then it should hold true for 10000D.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Actually you will need 9 comparisons. On the other hand, it would be possible that the 6 vectocs lay in a plane. If you choose a unit vector perpendicular to that plane you will not get any information.

Comment: You are right, I changed the number to 9. Are you saying that, since in such high dimensions each randomly picked vector is approximately orthogonal to each other, I will not be able to get information about their closeness by using a unit vector as the baseline?

Comment: WIthout more information on the geometry of your high dimensional vectors I think you will need all $9$ comparisons. You can save some arithmetic by computing the lengths first and reusing them rather than recomputing them for each dot product. It may be even better to normalize the vectors first (I haven't thought that through).